# PDF viewer not working when set the file data as Base64 using React

Tags: reactjs, base64, react-pdf

I am trying to display the PDF file in my react page using "react-pdf"package. I am getting the correct base64 file format from the Rest APi call, but file is not showing in UI.Once i get the data from API, the display message changed to Loading PDF…

[image]

Here is the base64 format getting from API

"data:application/pdf;base64,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...

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

this is your main component

```
<Worker workerUrl = "" >
   <Viewer fileUrl={file}
    plugins={[defaultLayoutPluginInstance]}/>
</Worker>
```

and file is

```
const file = `data:application/pdf;base64,${pdf}`
```

pdf is only just the text in base64, that is JVBERi0xLjUKJeLjz9MKMSAwIG9iajw8L1JvdGF0ZSAwL1BhcmVudCA0NTE3IDAgUi9.............................................

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).